# Package installation : dpkg parse error

Tags: terminal, apt, dpkg

Any time I try to install any new packages using `sudo apt-get install *package*`, I get the following error:

```
dpkg: parse error, in file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 95 package 'python-nova':
`Depends' field, invalid package name `python:any': character `:' not allowed (only letters, digits and characters `-+._')
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Can anyone provide me with steps to sort this out?

When I typed in `head -100 /var/lib/dpkg/status | tail -10` I got:

```
Architecture: all
Source: nova
Version: 1:2014.1.5-0ubuntu1.3
Provides: python2.7-nova
Depends: openssh-client, openssl, python-amqplib (>= 0.6.1), python-anyjson (>= 0.3.3), python-babel, python-boto (>= 2.4.0), python-cinderclient (>= 1:1.0.5), python-eventlet (>= 0.13.0), python-glanceclient (>= 1:0.9.0), python-greenlet (>= 0.3.2), python-iso8601, python-jinja2, python-jsonschema (>= 1.3.0), python-keystoneclient (>= 1:0.3.2), python-kombu (>= 2.5.12), python-lxml (>= 2.3), python-m2crypto, python-migrate, python-netaddr (>= 0.7.6), python-neutronclient (>= 1:2.3.0), python-oslo.config (>= 1:1.2.0), python-paramiko (>= 1.8.0), python-paste, python-pastedeploy (>= 1.5.0), python-pyasn1, python-pycadf (>= 0.1.9), python-routes, python-simplejson, python-six (>= 1.5.2), python-sqlalchemy-ext (>= 0.7.8-1~) | python-sqlalchemy (<< 0.6.3-2), python-stevedore (>= 0.12), python-suds, python-webob (>= 1.2.3), sudo, python (>= 2.7), python (<< 2.8), python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2), python-pbr, python-sqlalchemy (>= 0.8~), python-sqlalchemy (<< 0.9), python-oslo.rootwrap, python-oslo.messaging
Recommends: python-mysqldb
Suggests: python-ldap
Conflicts: python-cjson
Description: OpenStack Compute Python libraries
 OpenStack is a reliable cloud infrastructure. Its mission is to produce
```

Comment: Please revise question to include the output of `head -100 /var/lib/dpkg/status | tail -10`

Answer (score 1):

Somehow your `/var/lib/dpkg/status` got corrupted.

You could

1. Try to edit the file and fix it manually.
2. Try this solution from http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/debianproblem.htm

> **Recover package selection data**
>
> If `/var/lib/dpkg/status` becomes broken for any reason, the Debian
>   system loses package selection data and suffers severely. Look for the
>   old /var/lib/dpkg/status file at `/var/lib/dpkg/status-old` or
>   `/var/backups/dpkg.status.*`.
>
> Keeping `/var/backups/` in a separate partition may be a good idea since
>   this directory contains lots of important system data.
>
> If the old `/var/lib/dpkg/status` file is not available, you can still
>   recover information from directories in `/usr/share/doc/`.
>
> ```
> # ls /usr/share/doc | \
>   grep -v [A-Z] | \
>   grep -v '^texmf$' | \
>   grep -v '^debian$' | \
>   awk '{print $1 " install"}' | \
>   dpkg --set-selections
>
> # dselect --expert # reinstall system, de-select as needed
> ```

Comment: The file is not corrupted. The extract is valid. `python:any` is a valid package name with non-ancient versions of dpkg.